# Cannot update ubuntu on my home internet

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and a few days ago, my ubuntu has just started giving me these errors while I am trying to update && upgrade it.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eosrei/fonts/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/arc-gtk-theme-daily/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.169.110), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/InRelease  Could not connect to repo.steampowered.com:80 (195.175.116.167), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.steampowered.com:80 (195.175.116.151), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to linux.teamviewer.com:80 (52.222.167.150), connection timed out Could not connect to linux.teamviewer.com:80 (52.222.167.116), connection timed out Could not connect to linux.teamviewer.com:80 (52.222.167.142), connection timed out Could not connect to linux.teamviewer.com:80 (52.222.167.42), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultradvorka/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried many ways to solve it. The weird thing is, I can update && upgrade any other internet except my the home internet. Do you have any ideas?

It probably because of my router. To give a try, I installed another ubuntu alongside my current one. I got same errors there too.

Comment: Seems like have indeed conclusively demonstrated that the problem is your router, not your Ubuntu system. Good work troubleshooting!